# CAST or TO_TIMESTAMP function in Oracle from SQL?

Tags: python, sql-server, oracle, arcpy

I have a SQL query that was written for a SQL Server table and would like to translate/convert it to an Oracle query. How should this query be written to use `CAST` or `TO_TIMESTAMP` instead of `CONVERT`?

```
ticket_sql = "select {0} from {1} where {2} >= '{3}' and CONVERT(time, {4})  '{5}' and jobid NOT LIKE '%ZZ%' ".format(self.ticket_id_field, self.ticket_audit_table_name, self.modified_date_field, last_date, self.modified_time_field, last_time)
```

The field that is being converted is `self.modified_time_field` and is in the data in the following format: `11:13:38.682`

The above example is written for a Python application using ArcPy.

Comment: That looks like a time-of-day value (without a date). I don't know SQL Server, but I assume it may have a data type for such data. Oracle does not. Unless you are willing to keep that as a string (or better as a number) - a very bad idea for many reasons, either way - you will have to think hard about what that data represents and how it should be represented in the Oracle DATE or TIMESTAMP data type. (Perhaps in SQL Server you keep the date and the timestamp components separate? In Oracle they must be kept together). So, THIS is a question you need to address before you get to "how" to do it.

Comment: @mathguy Why wouldn't you use an `INTERVAL` to store a time-of-day value?  So, in the OP's case: `interval {4} hour to second(3)`?  (e.g., `interval '11:13:38.682' hour to second(3)`)

Comment: @gwestdev1 You should concatenate the `self.modified_date_field` and `self.modified_time_field` together and surround the concatenation with `TO_TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak - An interval measures the duration of an event or phenomenon, not the starting or ending time. There is a big difference between 4:30 a.m. and a duration of 4.5 hours. Intervals are for the latter, not the former. To put it another way: "a.m." and "p.m." and "hh24" are designations that make sense for `DATE` data type in Oracle; they make no sense for interval.

Comment: @mathguy Could someone needing to store only a time value not use an `INTERVAL` with the understanding that it is the interval from midnight until the time in question?  Practically speaking, why not store `INTERVAL '11:13:38.682' hour to second(3)` to mean `11:13.36.682 AM`?  It seems better than a string, which has no validation and no date/time arithmetic.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak - certainly better than a string. If I ever had to do something like this I would probably store it as a number (fraction of a day - should be >=0 and <1) but I suppose `interval` might work just as well. In most cases, though, I suspect these come from tables that also have a column for the "pure" date (with no time-of-day). Those should be combined together when moving to Oracle - if indeed that's how things are set up, or even "can" be set up, in another DB product. (Again, I don't even know if that's the case in SQL Server or any other database.)